# iterate selection over df pandas

Tags: python, loops, pandas, selection, rows

I have a `pandas DataFrame` converted from JSON and extracted the columns and rows I want (exported nicely to CSV).

However, I want to go a few "levels into the rows". I want to iterate a selection over my indexed data using somethin like:

```
df.likes[0]['count']
```

My DataFrame is called `df` and `likes` is the column. I want to access the value "count" over the entire row, printing it back into the same position and column of the DataFrame.

Here is the data:

```
>>> df_likes.ix[0:94]
0     {u'count': 1685, u'anchorStr': u'1225924030067...
1     {u'count': 1944, u'anchorStr': u'1225924022404...
2     {u'count': 2586, u'anchorStr': u'1225924194077...
3     {u'count': 3075, u'anchorStr': u'1225924298746...
4     {u'count': 3263, u'anchorStr': u'1225924358464...
5     {u'count': 3390, u'anchorStr': u'1225924289589...
6     {u'count': 4306, u'anchorStr': u'1225924191359...
7     {u'count': 751, u'anchorStr': u'12259244210391...
8     {u'count': 2425, u'anchorStr': u'1225924419831...
9     {u'count': 2628, u'anchorStr': u'1225924362763...
10    {u'count': 1521, u'anchorStr': u'1225924213802...
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "printing it back into the same position and column"?

Comment: Could you, if possible, please provide a short snippet of your input JSON-file? I am not sure, if you imported your data correctly since your DataFrame (which even could be a Series) looks kind of strange just containing these "subdicts" of your JSON-file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to access a cell value by using its index and column name, the following sample code does the job according to the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy.random import randn

df = DataFrame(randn(8, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

#access column with name 'A' and index 6
print(df['A'].ix[6])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you thought like this?

```
    anchorStr        ucount
0   1225924030067    1685
1   1225924022404    1944
2   1225924194077    2586
3   1225924298746    3075
4   1225924358464    3263
5   1225924289589    3390
6   1225924191359    4306
7   1225924421039     751
8   1225924419831    2425
9   1225924362763    2628
10  1225924213802    1521
```

If this is you think about, this code do the job.

```
from pandas import DataFrame as df

data = [
{u'count': 1685, u'anchorStr': u'1225924030067'},
{u'count': 1944, u'anchorStr': u'1225924022404'},
{u'count': 2586, u'anchorStr': u'1225924194077'},
{u'count': 3075, u'anchorStr': u'1225924298746'},
{u'count': 3263, u'anchorStr': u'1225924358464'},
{u'count': 3390, u'anchorStr': u'1225924289589'},
{u'count': 4306, u'anchorStr': u'1225924191359'},
{u'count': 751, u'anchorStr': u'1225924421039'},
{u'count': 2425, u'anchorStr': u'1225924419831'},
{u'count': 2628, u'anchorStr': u'1225924362763'},
...
{u'count': 1521, u'anchorStr': u'1225924213802'}]

c = [c['count'] for c in d]
a = [a['anchorStr'] for a in d]

d = df({'ucount': c, 'anchorStr': a})

print d
```

**Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)**